# interacting with GIS without the use of eyes

Tags: accessibility

I've been accepted to do gis, however, I'm not sure what tools are available to blind persons who are in the field. I would like to get information about various methods or tools that blind persons can use to study/work in the area of GIS. There are many ways for a blind person to read maps by touch, i however would like to interact with a map on the level of creating one digitally on the computer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols. Unfortunately, your question is too broad for focused Q&A but you can use the [tag:accessibility] tag to find Q&As that may be helpful to you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility?sort=votes

Comment: try Blind Audio Tactile Mapping System (BATS) http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/bats/

Answer (score 1):

To find questions related to accessibility tools that may be helpful to you click the [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) tag and sort on votes or click this link:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility?sort=votes

Users will usually only ask about the tools that they are using and find useful so this is a quick way to find accessibility tools that may be useful to you and at the same time learn how others are using them.